# Centering Logo In Landscape In UINavigationBar On iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uinavigationbar

In my iPhone app I have the following code to set the background image for both the landscape and portrait titlebar in the app.

```
if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"titlebar_landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"titlebar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];  
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
}
```

The image is the apps logo centered on a gradient background, which is re-sized for landscape accordingly.  I have done the same for my iPad version of the app, however the landscape image doesn't work, because there is no specific option for Landscape on the iPad like there is on the iPhone `UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone`.

**So my question is how to I achieve a similar effect on my iPad of my apps logo centered on a gradient background in landscape mode in iOS5?**

Comment: Apple Bug: this should be possible. The appearance system is pretty stupid if we still have to manually do this hacking (I have no idea how Apple failed to notice that apps use different backgrounds in different iPad orientations - Apple does it themself!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial on it, might help point you in the right direction. http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-customize-uinavigationbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-with-appearance-api.html

Comment: This is for the iPhone.  The problem is as the @john noted that the iPad uses the same metric for both orientations.  Which makes it difficult to center an image.

Answer (score 1):

iPad uses the same bar metrics regardless of orientation, so you should only have to set the UIBarMetricsDefault image.  The iPhone landscape metric is because the system uses a slightly shorter navigation bar on iPhone when in landscape mode.  All other navigation bars are the larger size, including any navigation bar shown on an iPad.

Comment: I understand that, but you missed the question. The question isn't how the iPad works, the question is how do I get an image centered in the landscape view in the title bar?

Comment: I assumed your images were just the same thing but adjusted to fit the two different heights.  If you must have a different background image for landscape mode on an iPad then you'll have to swap it out in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method in your UIViewController subclass.  Since iPad only uses one metric, you can't get the auto swapping behavior to do it for you in the UINavigationBar.